# Determining exact time between two touches

Tags: ios, swift, time, uiview

I am trying to determine the exact time the user has touched the screen. 
I have come up with this (inside my ViewController):

```
var startTime: Date?

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    startTime = Date()
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let endTime = Date()
    print(endTime.timeIntervalSince(startTime!))
}
```

Seems to work pretty well.
**Is this as precise as it gets? 
Is there a way to test how precise this is?**

Comment: first of all, you title is a little bit confusing. Please adjust that! Well, to test it, you either try to measure the time by sth. else or you need to have a second method which would do the same. But as I see it, when you want to measure the overall time from beginning to end of the touch this should be the best way to do it. But instead of using `Date` what do you think about the [Timestamp of an UITouch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch/1618144-timestamp)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for the same structure as you have done it. Your `print(endTime.timeIntervalSince(startTime!))` will print out a precise `Double` value for you.

I would tweak it a bit though, check comments for explanations:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    startTime = Date()
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    // Don´t use startTime!, use if let instead
    if let startTime = startTime {
        // Use 2 decimals on your difference, or 3, or whatever suits your needs best
        let difference = String(format: "%.2f", Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime))
        print(difference)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have found this to work well. Along with @Marcel T's comment about using the UITouches timestamp for additional accuracy.

Comment: @Marmelador, great!